# How to update two select boxes using one mysqli query in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

i have this php script with two select boxes in different divs on the page. A mysqli query retrieves the rows (data) from the database. My dilemma is how to jump the loop and continue a few lines down so i don't use two separate queries to get the same data

Example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="courseCode">Course Code</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="courseCode" id="courseCode">
             <option>Select Course Code</option>
              <?php 
                 $sql = "select course_code,course_title from courses";
                 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

                 if($result){
                   $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                   if($count > 0){
                      for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        $course_code = $row['course_code'];
                        $course_title =$row['course_title'];
                        echo'
                        <option value="'.$course_code.'">'.$course_code.'</option>';
                        }      
                     }   
                   }
                 }  
               ?>
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

$course_code is successfully populated from the database.

The question is how do i jump the html below so this loop continues and  $course_title is also populated using just the above script and i don't have to write the above lines over again.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="courseTitle">Course Title</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="courseTitle" id="courseTitle">
            <option>Select Course Title</option>
             <?php
                echo'<option value="'.$course_title.'">'.$course_title.'</option>'; ?>
            </select>
          </div>
    </div>
```

NB: course_code and course_title are just rows in course table.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the data gathering step out of the HTML and make it build 2 variables that you then use later in the HTML with a simple `echo`

```
<?php 
    $dd1 = '';
    $dd2 = '';

    $sql = "select course_code,course_title from courses";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 

    if($result){
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
              $dd1 .= '<option value="'.$row['course_code'].'">'.$row['course_code'].'</option>';
              $dd2 .= '<option value="'.$row['course_title'].'">'.$row['course_title'].'</option>';

          }      
       }
   }  
?>

<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="courseCode">Course Code</label>
         <select class="form-control" name="courseCode" id="courseCode">
             <option>Select Course Code</option>
             <?php echo $dd1; ?>
         </select>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="courseTitle">Course Title</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="courseTitle" id="courseTitle">
            <option>Select Course Title</option>
             <?php echo $dd2; ?>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that answer but now the it just displays the last ones. doesnt go through loop

Comment: Sorry, my TYPO check code again, now it loads `$dd1` and `$dd2`

Comment: jut did, pretty much still the same thing. it just displays the last item in d table and doesnt loop thru all

Comment: how do i make the loop apply outside that section of code?

Comment: I am having a bad day. Now changed the `$dd1 =` to `$dd1 .=` and you should get a full list now. Ditto with `$dd2`

Comment: sorry bout that, thanks for the help. I'ld give it a try now